# I'm writing an algorithm and am having trouble creating a functional boolean loop that stops when the statement is true

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, boolean

My algorithm gives instructions on how to make a cup of tea.

Several questions are asked and the user can answer with either 'yes' or 'no'.

I need help creating a loop, which triggers when the user answers with no. If the user answers with 'no' the algorithm should ask a question over and over until the user answers with 'yes'. When the user then answers with 'yes', after answering no 2-3 times, the loop should stop and the next question should be asked.

Ill paste the code I've written so far to illustrate it.

```
q1 = input ("Do you have these items in your kitchen?: cup, teaspoon, teabag, water boiler, 
teaspoon and sugar ?: ")
if q1 == 'yes':
  print "Great lets get started."
if q1 == 'no':
  print(" ")
  print "Please go to your local supermarket and purchase the items you do not have in your 
kitchen."
if q1 == 'no':
  a1 = input ("Have you gathered all the items now?: ")
  if a1 == 'yes':
    print ("Great lets get started.")
  else:
    while True:
      a2 = input ("Have you gathered all the items now?: ")
      yes = False
      if a2 == 'yes':
        print "Great lets get started"
```

Comment: Add `break` after the last `print` (and on the same indentation).

Comment: Is that python2 or python3? In python 3 you should have parentheses when calling `print`. But in python 2 you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the last while loop this way:

```py
ingredients_are_missing = True
while ingredients_are_missing:
    a2 = input ("Have you gathered all the items now?: ")
    ingredients_are_missing = not (a2 == 'yes')
print("Great lets get started")
```

Instead of an infinite loop `while True`, we now have a stopping condition. The stopping condition is a boolean variable, which already existed in your code (the variable you called `yes` and initialized with `yes = False`). I renamed this variable `ingredients_are_missing` so it's a little more explicit what it means.